# Python mail script and inserting variables into the html code

Tags: python, email

I tried to use templates and string formatting but nothing seemed to work.

I'm trying to prompt for user input so they can set a time in the html code. Here's a snippit of the code:

```
my_html = """\
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Something goes here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>When: &nbsp;</b>$the_time_goes_here</span></font></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
"""
the_time_goes_here = raw_input("What's the start time?\n")
```

I want to get "the_time_goes_here" to populate data in the html code.

Comment: This may be some toy project or something but you really need to bone up on your web programming. `font` tags have been deprecated since before the millennium, and there are so many good libraries for templating and HTML now that using strings like this is really a bottom of the barrel solution. Have you looked at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)? (I don't know what you're doing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use str.format using a placeholder `{}`  for the string pass into raw_input :

```
my_html = """\
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Something goes here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <font face="Calibri,sans-serif" size="2"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><b>When: &nbsp;</b>{0}</span></font></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
""".format(raw_input("What's the start time?\n"))
```

Comment: Oh, I think that would work if i weren't limited to python 2.6. I get the error: ```ValueError: zero length field name in format```          What's the work around for 2.6?

Comment: Oh that's excellent! Is there a way to add more variables? Sorry, stupid question.

Comment: yep, as many as you want, just  number each and pass them to format in the correct order 0,1,2 ...

Comment: No worries, you can use names also if you prefer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83156/discussion-between-mister-mister-and-padraic-cunningham).